# How do I "activate/trigger" a contact form script from my HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Alright so this site is 'done', but the contact form at the bottom doesn't work. 
Success response on the front end, but no email is generated.
It's Bootstrap so the legwork with this form was already done, yet I feel like theres some sort of connecting step that I'm missing. Still new to PHP/JS.

Here's the site: [PhaseHome](http://www.phasehome.com)

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <form name="sentMessage" form action="../mail/contact_me.php" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                            <div id="success"></div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The following contact_me.php file is in a mail folder in the root directory (left the client email in so no one would think that was the missing link) --

```
    <?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'steve@phasehome.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "www.phasehome.com Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "Hello Steve. You have received a new submission from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@phasehome.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

And finally, this **contact_me.js** was located in the js directory:

```
        $(function() {

    $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE:
Updated the HTML and JS, still no dice. Maybe I should mention, I just noticed this message in DreamWeaver on the `contact_me.php: "Dynamically-related files cannot be discovered because there is no site definition for this document"`  .. could that be the culprit?

UPDATE 2:

New contact_me.js in Dreamweaver is giving me a syntax error on line 29 ('cache false' just after your ajax suggestion).

```
    $(function() {

    $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "public_html/mail/contact_me.php",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: $('#contactForm').serialize(),
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

Comment: Your contact_me.js is the same as your contact_me.php? 0.o Ye.. that's not going to work..

Comment: HOw are you hosting your files? PHP requires some kind of server environment to run.

Comment: In a way this is my issue with frameworks like Bootstrap, they make gettign started too easy without getting a handle on the basics. You have jumped in the deepend a bit by going to an AJAX handler without understanding the way form submitting works on the back end or the HTTP response -> request -> response cycle works.

Comment: Jon, I've been weaning myself off of WYSIWYG stuff like Muse... I've used Bootstrap lately to help get me going with HTML/CSS, and every once in a while I run into this stuff. My stuff is hosted with GoDaddy, or localhost for testing. What you're seeing is live on my clients GoDaddy server.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your form does nothing! You need to either at an event handler to the button click or form submit for javascript functions or add an `action` attribute to the [form element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) to tell it what should handle the form submit:

```
<form action="/mail/contact_me.php" id="contactForm" method="post" novalidate >
```

Go with the action attribute, it is the simplest solution. Just make sure the path to your handling php file is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Add new hidden input to trigger form validation on ajax processor page. Add names to the inputs.

```
                <form action="" method="post" id="contactForm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="emailer" value="true" />
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" />
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" />
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" />
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                            <div id="success"></div>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-xl" value="SUBMIT" \>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Remove default action of the form, get actual feedback from ajax.

```
               $.ajax({
            url: "/mail/contact_me.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $('#contactForm').serialize(),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result) {
                        $('#success').html(result);

                        /*
                        // Success message
                        $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                        $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                            .append("</button>");
                        $('#success > .alert-success')
                            .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                        $('#success > .alert-success')
                            .append('</div>');  
                        */

                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },...etc.
```

Filter email so it's valid on the processing page.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['emailer'])) {
        if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == true) {
                $name           =   strip_tags($_POST['name']);
                $email_address  =   $_POST['email'];
                $phone          =   $_POST['phone'];
                $message        =   strip_tags($_POST['message']);

                // Create the email and send the message
             // $to_alt         =   $email_address;
                $to             =   "steve@phasehome.com";
                $email_subject  =   "www.phasehome.com Contact Form:  $name";
                $email_body     =   "Hello Steve. You have received a new submission from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
                $headers        =   "From: noreply@phasehome.com\n";
                $headers        .=  "Reply-To: $email_address"; 

                // Send copy to sender
                // mail($to_alt ,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
                // Send original to intended
                if(!mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)) { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times</button>
                    <strong>Message failed to send.</strong></div>
                </div>
                 <?php }
                else { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times</button>
                    <strong>Your message has been sent. </strong></div>
                </div>
                 <?php }
            }
        else { ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times</button>
            <strong>Email Invalid!</strong></div>
        </div>
         <?php }
    } ?>
```

Make sure GoDaddy doesn't give you bad info......

Comment: Well I updated the PHP file fine, and tried replacing my form with the submission page section (including js?) and still nothing. I'm really sorry about my naiveté, I'm getting into uncharted territory for myself with JS/Ajax/PHP... and this is the last piece to this project, of course. I'll bake you cookies if you can help me get this working.

Comment: Where is this link in relation to your root directory? That may be easier to put in then backing out of current directory.

Comment: Well now I'm really lost.... I realized that the mail folder actually isn't in the root dir, but in a public_html folder. So I updated that link and now I'm actually getting a failed server not responding message. Progress.

Comment: Success message is all well and good, but when I'm checking the destination email and have nothing.

Comment: Made the updates to www.phasehome.com ... still getting server not responding error.

Comment: ALRIGHT, updated it was you mentioned, now I'm getting a green success message, but still no actual email to his account.... does the 'noreply@..." email in the Javascript and PHP actually have to exist or is that just for codings sake? the only account on his server is steve@phasehome.com

Comment: Rasclatt I hugely appreciate your time. Still no dice... again, jquery and what not is over my head (Hi, graphic designer learning web dev through trial by fire!)

How can I resolve that issue you mentioned? Is this beyond repair?

Comment: Well now upon submission it refreshed the page to the top... no email. I think I should clarify, the contact_me.php isn't in the ROOT mail folder, that was already there from GoDaddy... it's actually in ../public_html/mail/contact_me.php ... I'll try updating the paths and see.

Comment: And after that page re-load, if I try to manually refresh, I get the "are you sure you want to leave this page" dialog. I just commented out that javascript in case I had to re-add it... also updated the file paths to contact_me.php   ... if you have any ideas I'd appreciate it man. Learning everyday...

Comment: added it back. is this something I can fix by tweaking what's there?

Comment: made your updates despite syntax error. updated my question with update 2.

Comment: @weslangdon Could you please share your work with me ? Your website is exactly what I was looking for. Is your issue with email sending resolved? I have hosted my site on my own VPS from bandwagonhost and I am getting same error. Don't know if email server needs to be installed on the VPS.

Comment: @rahoolm Which error are you getting? I resolved this for him, but we connected outside of SO and I remoted to his machine. If I recall, his theme javascript was messing with his custom javascript.